# How to iterate through a defaultdict(list) in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iterator, defaultdict

How do i iterate through a defaultdict(list) in Python?
Is there a better way of having a dictionary of lists in Python?
I've tried the normal `iter(dict)` but I've got the error:

```
>>> import para
>>> para.print_doc('./sentseg_en/essentials.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "para.py", line 31, in print_doc
    for para in iter(doc):
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

The main class:

```
import para
para.print_doc('./foo/bar/para-lines.txt')
```

The para.pyc:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
## Modified paragraph into a defaultdict(list) structure
## Original code from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66063/
from collections import defaultdict
class Paragraphs:
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    # Separator here refers to the paragraph seperator,
    #  the default separator is '\n'.
    def __init__(self, filename, separator=None):
        # Set separator if passed into object's parameter,
        #  else set default separator as '\n'
        if separator is None:
            def separator(line): return line == '\n'
        elif not callable(separator):
            raise TypeError, "separator argument must be callable"
        self.separator = separator
        # Reading lines from files into a dictionary of lists
        self.doc = defaultdict(list)
        paraIndex = 0
        with open(filename) as readFile:
            for line in readFile:
                if line == separator:
                    paraIndex+=1
                else:
                    self.doc[paraIndex].append(line)

# Prints out populated doc from txtfile
def print_doc(filename):
    text = Paragraphs(filename)
    for para in iter(text.doc):
        for sent in text.doc[para]:
            print "Para#%d, Sent#%d: %s" % (
                para, text.doc[para].index(sent), sent)
```

An e.g. of `./foo/bar/para-lines.txt` looks like this:

```
This is a start of a paragraph.
foo barr
bar foo
foo foo
This is the end.

This is the start of next para.
foo boo bar bar
this is the end.
```

The output of the main class should look like this:

```
Para#1,Sent#1: This is a start of a paragraph.
Para#1,Sent#2: foo barr
Para#1,Sent#3: bar foo
Para#1,Sent#4: foo foo
Para#1,Sent#5: This is the end.

Para#2,Sent#1: This is the start of next para.
Para#2,Sent#2: foo boo bar bar
Para#2,Sent#3: this is the end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe you linked to is rather old. It was written in 2001 before Python had more modern tools like [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (introduced in Python2.4, [released in late 2003](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0320/)). Here is what your code could look like using `groupby`:

```
import itertools
import sys

with open('para-lines.txt', 'r') as f:
    paranum = 0
    for is_separator, paragraph in itertools.groupby(f, lambda line: line == '\n'):
        if is_separator:
            # we've reached paragraph separator
            print
        else:
            paranum += 1
            for n, sentence in enumerate(paragraph, start = 1):
                sys.stdout.write(
                    'Para#{i:d},Sent#{n:d}: {s}'.format(
                        i = paranum, n = n, s = sentence))
```

Comment: Am I right to say that when i get out of the `for` loop, the `paragraph` would have ran out of scope? How do i keep the paragraph and continue to access it outside of the `itertools.groupby` loop?

Comment: No, the name `paragraph` doesn't go out of scope. Python doesn't open new scopes for block constructs like `with` and `for`, just for functions.

Comment: `paragraph` is reassigned to a new value each time through the loop. If you wish to keep old paragraphs, you could define a list `paragraphs = []` outside the loop, and append each paragraph to it inside the loop: `paragraphs.append(paragraph)`.

Comment: I read in your comment to Daniel Roseman that the text file is large. Trying to save all the paragraphs in a list (or a dict) may take a lot of memory. Do you need them all or maybe just the previous n paragraphs (use deque)? Do you need to access them randomly (use dict) or iteratively (use list or deque)? Knowing what you need the paragraphs for will influence our recommendation for the best algorithm / data structure to use.

Comment: I need to cross-reference and check for similarity from another document with similar paragraph and align the sentences inside the paragraphs. Technically speaking, i have at least 150 textfiles each with 3-10 paragraphs and each paragraph have 5-6 sentences with at least 200-300 chars per sentences. 150*7*5*250 chars inside my dict. Shouldn't be a problem i think. But after the test code, i will need to scale the system up to 1500 texts with 50 paragraphs each, i think that will become a problem.

Comment: Practically, I would only need to read 2 files at each time to compare similarity, so it shouldn't be a problem as long as i dump the dict after outputing the similarity score.

Comment: Given two files, do the corresponding paragraphs come in the same order in both files? After comparing corresponding paragraphs, do you need to keep the paragraphs any longer, or did you need to save the paragraphs simply to load by files one after the other?

Comment: The paragraphs might/might not come in the same order, thus the similarity task. The sentences certainly don't come in the same order. After comparing the paragraphs, the matching sentences with the index will be written into another file.

Comment: Since the corresponding paragraphs may come in any order, I don't see anything clever you can do other than store the entire collection of paragraphs in a list. I don't think you'll have a problem storing two such files in memory at a time.

Comment: I've the `Paragraphs` class handling and storing it as a defaultdict and then during the comparison, i'll be making a separate class to read the `defaultdict(list)` into a sequential list and then outputs the comparison statistics.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with line

```
for para in iter(doc):
```

is that `doc` is an instance of Paragraph, not a `defaultdict`.  The default dict you use in the `__init__` method goes out of scope and is lost. So you need to do two things:

1. Save the `doc` created in the `__init__` method as an instance variable (`self.doc`, for example).
2. Either make `Paragraphs` itself iterable (by adding an `__iter__` method), or allow it to access the created `doc` object.

Comment: i tried saving the `doc` and `self.doc` in `self.doc = defaultdict(list)` and `self.doc[paraIndex].append(line)`. But the same out of scope problem happens.

Comment: @2er0: It is in scope, but as `doc.doc` (which means there is also a naming problem -- you should use something like `paragraphs` instead of `doc` in `print_doc`).

Comment: Yep thanks for noting the naming problem, after some minor changes the iteration works. But let me see whether i can combine the `self.doc` solution with unutbu's loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're iterating over your `Paragraphs` class, not the dictionary. Also, instead of iterating over keys and then accessing the dictionary entry, consider using

```
for (key, value) in d.items():
```

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because you don't have `__iter__()` defined in your Paragraphs class and then try to call `iter(doc)` (where doc is a Paragraphs instance).

To be iterable a class has to have `__iter__()` which returns iterator. [Docs here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why you're using a dict here, let alone a defaultdict. A list of list would be much simpler.

```
doc = []
with open(filename) as readFile:
    para = []
    for line in readFile:
        if line == separator:
            doc.append(para)
            para = []
        else:
            para.append(line)
    doc.append(para)
```

Comment: it's because my txt file will be a large txtfile, so accessing through a nested list is going to take up a lot of time. Maybe i will need a Dictionary of dictionary. What shall i do if i want dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: How does that follow? Why do you think a nested list will take longer than a dict of dicts?